# How to get selected text from a SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a custom helper method for a Drop Down List with the following signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

Within the method, I can do the following to get the selected value:

```
var Value = ((SelectList)selectList).SelectedValue);
```

In my helper method, I need to find out what the selected text is as well, and not just the value. How will I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have selected value you can just iterate through the `IEnumerable` trying to find the selected `SelectListItem`:

```
        SelectListItem[] items = selectList.ToArray();
        SelectListItem selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == valueAsString) 
            ?? items[0];
        string selectedText = selectedItem.Text;
```

From my opinion, casting to `SelectList` is not the best option to find selected value, this casting could throw `InvalidCastException` when real type of `selectList` variable is other than `SelectList`.

In most cases your model contains a value that should be selected in the drop down list. You can get this value using `ModelMetadata` classes as follows:

```
        //Get value from model or from ModelState
        object modelValue = ModelMetadata
             .FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData).Model;

        SelectListItem[] items = selectList.ToArray();

        string selectedValue = modelValue == null ? null : modelValue.ToString();

        SelectListItem selectedItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == selectedValue) 
            ?? items.FirstOrDefault();

        string selectedText = selectedItem == null ? null : selectedItem.Text;

        //Rest code goes here
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip and the answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
  public static string getText(SelectList selectList)
  {            
    string text =  selectList.Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault().Text;
    return text; 
  }
```

Comment: The line can be simplified with `string text =  selectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected).Text;`.